# Bootsrap Data Attributes not working

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

First of all i wanted to put an icon inside an option but i could not figure out why it wont work after a while i realized that none of the data attributes works while my external .js file works fine ,and  me having no changes made to the bootsrap files.
**Worth notice**
I run the website at a local server(xampp). I also have some php in there(never had any problem with).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--conecting link to boostrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/workshop.css">  <!-- conectin link to css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="pull-left">

                   <select class="selectpicker " style="width: 100px; height: 29px;">
                      <option selected disabled style="color: red;">Categories</option>

                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                  </select>

                  </div>



                   <div class="pull-right">

                   <select class="selectpicker "data-style="btn-primary" style="width: 68px; height: 29px;">
                      <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">Public </option>
                      <option>Private</option>
                  </select>


                      <input id="botton2" type="submit" value="Post" />





            </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  <!--conecting link to js -->
<script src="js/workshop.js"></script>          

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: did you leave out the </html> on this post? you have to put a space between " and data

Comment: @mlegg fixed the </html> , no the space it's not it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the bootstrap-select plugin without including its CSS and JS into your code.

[Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

If you include it, then it works fine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.2/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--conecting link to boostrap -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/workshop.css">  <!-- conectin link to css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="pull-left">

                   <select class="selectpicker " style="width: 100px; height: 29px;">
                      <option selected disabled style="color: red;">Categories</option>

                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                      <option>Random</option>
                  </select>

                  </div>



                   <div class="pull-right">

                   <select class="selectpicker "data-style="btn-primary" style="width: 68px; height: 29px;">
                      <option data-icon="glyphicon-heart">Public </option>
                      <option>Private</option>
                  </select>


                      <input id="botton2" type="submit" value="Post" />





            </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  <!--conecting link to js -->
<script src="js/workshop.js"></script>          

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir I honestly thought i had included it and you saved me a lot of time thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To use glyphicons you add them as a class(not a data-attribute) to either a 'span' or 'i' element within the option not to the option itself.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_glyphicons.asp

Comment: but look at this (go to Customize options/icons ): https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: That documentation is for a jQuery Plugin for Bootstrap that I don't see a script tag referencing in your code.